# Handling onClick and receiver events in Android widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

Currently I have a service, TimerService, that broadcasts updates, milestones, and alerts.

In the manifest file:

```
    <!-- WIDGET! -->
    <service android:name=".UpdateWidgetService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" ></service>
    <receiver
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="JustInTime"
        android:name="com.JustInTime.widget.WidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

Would the UpdateWidgetService register receivers for the TimerService?  It seems wrong that one service is listening to another service like this.  Also, is it normal to register onClick functionality within the widget, or do you have to use setOnClickPendingIntent?

Goal: To have a widget that works like an alarm clock that listen to broadcasts from a service and then updates the widget as it needs.  This update should update the UI, where there are several view items.

If you have good widget examples from this, please share.  Most of them are very basic from what I see.